# What date formats can Apache Commons GenericValidator.isDate handle in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I want to validate if my string contains a valid date. My simplified code is:

```
String createdAt = "2022-06-08T21:11:31.710Z";
assertTrue(GenericValidator.isDate(createdAt, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", true));
```

It looks like datetime format is correct but I receive

```
expected: <true> but was: <false>
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

Please tell me if GenericValidator.isDate can't handle this format or smth is wrong elsewhere?

Comment: It’s a long shot. From [the docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/GenericValidator.html#isDate-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-): *If strict is true, then the length will be checked so '2/12/1999' will not pass validation with the format 'MM/dd/yyyy' because the month isn't two digits.* Might this mean that since `'T'` and `'Z'` are longer than `T` and `Z`, the validator fails the validation?

Comment: In 2022 I would prefer to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for validation. Try to parse, and catch the `DateTimeParseException` that comes out of a wrong format, date or time.

Comment: My shot was not too long to be correct. In [the source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/DateValidator.html) I found this line: `if (strict && (datePattern.length() != value.length())) {`. This suffices to fail your validation. In my book it’s a bug in the Apache validator design.

Comment: `Instant.parse(createdAt)` should suffice for validating your string. It will accept fewer or more fractional decimals (up to 9 of them), which for the majority of purposes would not be a problem.